# What happens if a request object contains a property which doesn't have a corresponding model property?

Tags: c#, oop, http-post, postman

Say your endpoint expects a model of

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

and you make a request from Postman etc. with a JSON object of

```
{
  "forename": "Joe",
  "surname": "Bloggs",
  "age": 50
}
```

As you can see, "age" doesn't have a corresponding property so it never becomes part of the application's object. It doesn't error or anything when you submit the request like it would if you'd missed a required field and validation kicked in...so what actually happens to the data? Is it simply lost in the ether? Do applications like Postman identify the destination object before sending the body and simply exclude non-matching properties?

Comment: It's lost in the ether as you say during the deserialization process (it's not actually - it would still be part of the request context body during the entirety of the API pipeline process)

Comment: It depends, different deserializers behave differently. Some will throw error, some will deserialize them dynamicly and process (for example, they can return it back even if they don't know what they received, WCF can do this by using extensible objects)